# How to run an autocommand after undo?

Tags: autocmd

I want to run an autocommand to restore cursor position after undoing with `u`. After reading the documentation for [event](https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#CmdlineEnter), I cannot find a event that is specified for undoing. Which event should I be using?

Comment: there does not exist one. You may be able to map the `u` key

Comment: There's no autocmd for undo. The way you would usually hook into the "undo" operation is by creating a mapping for the `u` key, so that it will trigger whatever code you'd like to run around that operation.

Comment: Possible to create one with TextChanged + undotree()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [@Mass's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/how-to-run-an-autocommand-after-undo#comment56945_31230), you might be able to get started with

```
augroup whatever
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChanged * call F()
augroup END

function F() abort
  const undotree = undotree()
  if undotree.seq_cur is# undotree.seq_last
    " no undos
    return
  endif
  " your work here…
endfunction
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks